# Am I deserializing my JSON object incorrectly in GetProductAsync?

Tags: c#, json, async-await, httpclient

When I run this piece of code, I get the following error message:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'HttpClientSample.Product' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

I thought I told my client to return a JSON......Do I need to convert my response (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject)? if so, to a List ?

A typical response using postman would be:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test",
        "inactive": false           
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test2",
        "inactive": false           
    }
]
```

Thank you

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace HttpClientSample
{
   public class Product
  {

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
  } 

class Program
{

    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
        Product product = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.id, product.name, product.inactive);
        }
        return product;
    }


    static void Main()
    {
       // RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {


        // Update port # in the following line.
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:51075/api/products");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        try
        {

            Product product = new Product();

            // Get the product
            product = await GetProductAsync("https://localhost:51075/api/products");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is up to you to decide if getting an error is correct behavior of your code or not (how we'd find out what you actually expect?)... Are you sure the question in the title is exactly what you need to know?

Comment: The square brackets in your “typical response” denote a list (of Product items). So you need to change the generic parameter of your ReadAsAsync method accordingly.

Comment: Its just a matter of whether your expecting a single `Product` or an array of `Product`. Deserialize which ever you're expecting. It looks like you're expecting an array with one element, that still needs to be deserialized as an array or other collection.

Comment: Error seems straightforward. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: Updated the response example I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE with the answer** :) 
The GetResponseAsync function:

```
public static async Task<SetupWebApiResponse> GetResponseAsync(string 
        endpoint)
    {

        string result = "";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        return new SetupWebApiResponse(response.StatusCode, result);

    }
```

The SetupWebApiResponse class:

```
public class SetupWebApiResponse
{
    public SetupWebApiResponse() { }

    public SetupWebApiResponse(int statusCode, object responseBody)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
        this.ResponseBody = responseBody;
    }

    public SetupWebApiResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object responseBody)
        : this((int)statusCode, responseBody)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the HTTP status code of the response
    /// </summary>
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the response body content
    /// </summary>
    public object ResponseBody { get; set; }
}
```

The SetupWebAI class:

```
  public class SetupWebAPI
 {

    static string User;
    static string Password;
    static string Endpoint;
    static object Content;

    static SetupWebApiResponse apiResponse;

    public static SetupWebApiResponse GetResponseInStringFormat(string user, string password, string endpoint)
    {
        User = user;
        Password = password;
        Endpoint = endpoint;
        ExecuteResponse().Wait();
        return apiResponse;
    }
    private static async Task ExecuteResponse()
    {
        SetupWebAPIAsync.SetAPIAuthentication(User, Password);
        apiResponse = await SetupWebAPIAsync.GetResponseAsync(Endpoint);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Your problem seems to be that you have a malformed JSON array. In order to get my example to work I had to add a comma after the }, <<<---

This is what I do:

- Copy JSON object string text
- In visual studio I use "Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON as Classes" -
- in a new .cs file inside the namespace part.

Example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public class Product
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public bool inactive { get; set; }
        }

        public void testingClass()
        {
            string testJSONResponse = @"
    [{
                ""id"": ""1"",
        ""name"": ""test"",
        ""inactive"": false
    },]
";
            var myNewCSharpObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product[]>(testJSONResponse);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you think this advice actually applies to the described issue?

Comment: I forgot the array part... fixed.

Comment: You didn't explain why this was necessary. And why don't you just use the classes that the question already describes?

Comment: No, it is not a malformed JSON array. The question clearly describes the error.

Comment: updated it again.... also found that the array is not right in the json

Comment: Hi guys, yes my response is not always a single one, it is an array (basically I can return hundreds of products, different ID, names, etc....)

Comment: @fazlook1, try my solution, it should deserialize just fine. have you tried? product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product[]>();

Comment: @Omzig I appreciate your help, however that did not work. my function must return a list of products or an array of products...I am still reading how Task<> works. I am trying  string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync(); List<Product> product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(result); I will see how my return works

Comment: @fazlook1, I would like to help more, but I would have to recreate a REST service that mimics your setup :(, I do not have time right now. JSON is such a pain, when I get into some of these issues with JSON, I end up going XML REST... LOL, oh btw, if you can get it into an array you can do .ToList(), if the JsonConvert likes that better.

Comment: @Omzig hehe. I figured it out :) it works now. I have to do the same thing in XML soon :) is there a private messaging here ?

Comment: @faszlook1, YAY!!! no I don't think there is private messaging... please post a solution and check it, these goobers keep down voting this subject.

Comment: @Omzig yes man :) had to read lots of documentations and finally worked. Easier than I thought. The GET part works. Now I am suffering with the PUT part.

Comment: @fazlook1, remember to mark solution, or create your own answer to mark as the solution. it might help someone else in the future ;)

Comment: click on Answer my question and write the solution ?